# How do I configure JxBrowser to automatically persist cookie and use them automatically to login site?

Tags: jxbrowser

I am using JxBrowser v7.10 in mac and have some cookie issues on persisting them and use them automatically to autologin site on application restart. It seems that cookies fail to persist somehow.

I searched and read the documentation in
https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/cookies.html#working-with-cookies
https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/javadoc/7.2/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/cookie/CookieStore.html

and yet could not find how to use the cookie.

The doc mentions
"JxBrowser delegates the work with cookies to the Chromium engine. Chromium decides how to download cookies from a web server, extract them from the HTTP headers and store them in a local file system (persistent cookies) or in the memory (session cookies)."

So from that understanding, the cookie should be auto-persist and able to use them on application restart , but instead I need to relogin everytime the application restart.

The following is the test code . I should be able to login gmail and jxbrowser auto persist the cookie (no coding require) and autologin gmail on restart , however the following code fail to do that .

Is that something I need to do to implement that ?

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.browser.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.Engine;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.EngineOptions;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.swing.BrowserView;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import static com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.RenderingMode.HARDWARE_ACCELERATED;

public final class CookieBrowser {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Creating and running Chromium engine
    final Engine engine = Engine.newInstance(
      EngineOptions.newBuilder(HARDWARE_ACCELERATED).build());

    Browser browser = engine.newBrowser();
    // Loading the required web page
    browser.navigation().loadUrl("www.gmail.com");

    // No cookie printed out, why ?
    engine.cookieStore().cookies().forEach(System.out::println);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
      // Creating Swing component for rendering web content
      // loaded in the given Browser instance
      BrowserView view = BrowserView.newInstance(browser);

      // Creating and displaying Swing app frame
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("JxBrowser AWT/Swing");
      // Closing the engine when app frame is about to close
      frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
          System.out.println("Cookie persist"); // but unable to use them automatically on restart
          engine.cookieStore().persist();
          engine.close();
        }
      });

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame.setSize(800, 600);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: Why do you think that providing the required persistent/session cookies is enough to tell Google to automatically sign in? Even if it's true, you should know what cookies you should set. To print the cookies, load URL using loadUrlAndWait().

Comment: Hi,  Vladimir, 
thank for the response. Let me rephrase it this way. How can I make JxBrowser behave like standard browser whereby it can login to sites (not only gmail) if there is already persistent cookie on restart. So on the user's side, they don't have to know how to handle the cookie, they just enable cookie in browser and browser will take care of it.  

If JxBrowser behave otherwise, what exactly the step I need to do auto-login ?

Comment: isn't browsercontext not enough for achieving that result?

Answer (score 3):

You get this behavior because you don't configure the `Engine` instance with the user data directory. So, every time you create a new `Engine` instance, a temp directory will be created and the cookie store will be initialized there. As a result, all the previously created cookies will not be available anymore.

Please check out the guide at https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/engine.html#user-data-directory

From that guide:

**User Data Directory**

Represents an absolute path to the directory where the data such as cache, cookies, history, GPU cache, local storage, visited links, web data, spell checking dictionary files, etc. is stored. For example:

```java
Engine engine = Engine.newInstance(EngineOptions.newBuilder(...)
        .userDataDir(Paths.get("/Users/Me/.jxbrowser"))
        .build());
```

If you do not provide the user data directory path, JxBrowser will create and use a temp directory in the user’s temp folder.

FYI: Just in case I will mention this info in the Cookies guide as well.

Comment: Hi Vladimir,
I have set userDataDir and now that desired behavior works.
thank for the solution.